# Is a 10mph gust of wind the only thing that can disperse the Harmless Insect Swarm from the Staff of Swarming Insects?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

The Staff of Swarming Insects (DMG, pp 203) allows you to :

> Spend an action...to cause a swarm of harmless flying insects to spread out in a 30'foot radius from you

And it lists that:

> The insects remain for 10 minutes...A wind of at least 10 miles per hour disperses the swarm and ends the effect.

Is a strong gust wind of at least 10mph the only way to disperse/remove the swarm? Can it be reduced/attacked by other phenomena (direct damage, webs, fire, etc.)?

Comment: yes indeed......

Comment: This item/effect is a perfect reminder that D&D simply isn't a simulation because fireball would definitely disband the swarm if it were

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### An Anti-magic field could potentially have an effect:

An [anti-magic field](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/antimagic-field) has the following effects:

> A 10-foot-radius invisible sphere of antimagic surrounds you. This area is divorced from the magical energy that suffuses the multiverse. Within the sphere, spells can't be cast, summoned creatures disappear, and even magic items become mundane. Until the spell ends, the sphere moves with you, centered on you.
>
> Spells and other magical effects, except those created by an artifact or a deity, are suppressed in the sphere and can't protrude into it. A slot expended to cast a suppressed spell is consumed. While an effect is suppressed, it doesn't function, but the time it spends suppressed counts against its duration.

If the swarm is a magical effect, then it will cease to exist as long as it overlaps with an anti-magic field. The [sage advice compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf) states that an effect is definitely magical if it fulfills one of the following criteria:

> • Is it a magic item?
>
> • Is it a spell? Or does it let you create the effects of a spell
> that’s mentioned in its description?
>
> • Is it a spell attack?
>
> • Is it fueled by the use of spell slots?
>
> • Does its description say it’s magical?

The effect of the swarm doesn't necessarily meet these criteria, but it is created by expending charges from a magical item, and the swarm could maybe be considered "summoned creatures." So, there is an argument for the anti-magic field to have an effect, but I would definitely ask your DM for a definitive call here. Also, the field won't disperse the swarm completely, but rather cause any part of the swarm that overlaps with the field to disappear, though the swarm would reappear if moves out from the anti-magic field, or if the field ends.

#### Aside from that, RAW suggests no.

Typically, we assume that an effect does exactly what it says and nothing more. Since the effect of the swarm doesn't mention that the insects can be burned, attacked, or otherwise dispersed by anything other than a strong wind, then any attempt to do something resembling that would be futile. It would take the specific effect of a separate ability, like anti-magic field, that explicitly removes the effect to disperse it.

Of course, your DM could rule otherwise, based on the idea that the insects are all still creatures. But the swarm has no stat block; so no ability scores, hit points, or really anything that defines a "creature" in 5e. So at that point, you get deep into DM ruling territory as to how any effect that works on "creatures" affects the swarm.

Comment: Is there an example of non-summoned creatures counting as summoned? The "summoning" spells (aka Conjure) are bring in Fey creatures that look/act like real creatures. These are pure mundane harmless insects.

Comment: @NautArch I don't think so. If the insects are only being controlled, rather than magically created, then we could liken the result to a spell like [Dominate Beast](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dominate-beast). In that case, going into the field would remove the staff's control over the insect swarm, but then the DM would get to decide how the swarm reacts.